# How to wire Honeywell MT1 THR830TEU

Tags: thermostat

Where do the 4 wires go?

The diagram isn't very helpful.

Live into 1
Neutral into 2
Earth into earth

What number does the 4th wire go into 3 or 4?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the diagram that Andrew didn't find helpful:

[image: Honewell wiring diagram and instructions]

It's pretty obvious to me, though it would have been *more* obvious if they showed the switch in heating position for the heating diagram.

It's a heating **or** cooling thermostat. A heating load goes on 3, a cooling load goes on 4. There's required fusing as stated below the diagram.